# how to force download file pdf in partialjs (nodejs)

Tags: jquery, node.js, http-headers, download

im working with partialjs and have question, how to force download with partialjs?

my codes do something like this:

html:

```
<a href="/media/document.pdf" class="download-button">Download pdf</a>
```

i use jquery [filedownload](https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload), which is working well download 'zip' file for example, but failed on 'pdf' due to this kind of http header setting that i dont know where to set in the nodejs/partialjs.

javascript (jquery):

```
  $('.download-button').on('click', function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var filePath =$(this).attr('href');   
       // jquery do something here
       //...
      $.fileDownload(filePath); 
  });
```

please enlight me..

Comment: `$('download-button')` custom `tag` ? , or missing `#` , `.` before `download-button` ? What is result with utilizing only `html` portion ? , without `.on()` ? At OP , `href` of `a` element appear to include url to resource ? `click` on `a` element not create file download dialog ?

Comment: yep updated. the problem is not the selector..and it use preventdefault as updated